# Prove that for any family of sets $\mathcal F$, $\bigcup!\mathcal F=\bigcup\mathcal F$ iff $\mathcal F$ is pairwise disjoint.

Tags: elementary-set-theory, proof-writing, solution-verification

Not a duplicate of

[Prove that for any family of sets $\mathcal F$, $∪!\mathcal F = ∪\mathcal F$ iff $\mathcal F$ is pairwise disjoint.](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2403857/prove-that-for-any-family-of-sets-mathcal-f-%e2%88%aa-mathcal-f-%e2%88%aa-mathcal-f-iff)

This is exercise $3.6.5.a$ from the book *How to Prove it* by Velleman $($$2^{nd}$ edition$)$:

Prove that for any family of sets $\mathcal F$, $\bigcup!\mathcal F\subseteq\bigcup\mathcal F$.

I call the above statement "lemma $1$" for convenience and prove it as follows:

Let $x$ be an arbitrary element of $\bigcup!\mathcal F$. So there exists a unique set $A_0$ such that $A_0\in\mathcal F$ and $x\in A_0$. Ergo $x\in\bigcup\mathcal F$. Therefore if $x\in\bigcup!\mathcal F$ then $x\in\bigcup\mathcal F$. Since $x$ is arbitrary, $\forall x(x\in\bigcup!\mathcal F\rightarrow x\in\bigcup\mathcal F)$ and so $\bigcup!\mathcal F\subseteq\bigcup\mathcal F$. $Q.E.D.$

This is exercise $3.6.5.b$ from the book *How to Prove it* by Velleman $($$2^{nd}$ edition$)$:

A family of sets $\mathcal F$ is said to be pairwise disjoint if every pair of distinct elements of $\mathcal F$ are disjoint; that is, $\forall A\in\mathcal F\forall B\in\mathcal F(A\neq B\rightarrow A\cap B=\emptyset)$. Prove that for any family of sets $\mathcal F$, $\bigcup!\mathcal F=\bigcup\mathcal F$ iff $\mathcal F$ is pairwise disjoint.

Here is my proof:

$(\rightarrow)$ Suppose $\bigcup!\mathcal F=\bigcup\mathcal F$. Let $A$ and $B$ be arbitrary elements of $\mathcal F$ such that $A\neq B$. Let $x$ be an arbitrary element of $A$. From $A\in \mathcal F$ and $x\in A$, $x\in\bigcup\mathcal F$. Since $\bigcup!\mathcal F=\bigcup\mathcal F$, $x\in\bigcup!\mathcal F$. Since $x\in\bigcup!\mathcal F$, from $x\in A$ and $A\neq B$ we obtain $x\notin B$. Ergo if $x\in A$ then $x\notin B$. Since $x$ is arbitrary, $\forall x(x\in A\rightarrow x\notin B)$ and so $A\cap B=\emptyset$. Thus if $A\neq B$ then $A\cap B=\emptyset$. Since $A$ and $B$ are arbitrary, $\forall A\in\mathcal F\forall B\in\mathcal F(A\neq B\rightarrow A\cap B=\emptyset)$ and so $\mathcal F$ is pairwise disjoint. Therefore if $\bigcup!\mathcal F=\bigcup\mathcal F$ then $\mathcal F$ is pairwise disjoint.

$(\leftarrow)$ Suppose $\mathcal F$ is pairwise disjoint. This means $\forall A\in\mathcal F\forall B\in\mathcal F(A\neq B\rightarrow A\cap B=\emptyset)$. Let $x$ be an arbitrary element of $\bigcup\mathcal F$. So we can choose some $A_0$ such that $A_0\in\mathcal F$ and $x\in A_0$. Suppose $x\notin \bigcup!\mathcal F$. Now we consider two cases.

Case $1.$ Suppose $x\notin \bigcup\mathcal F$. From $x\notin \bigcup\mathcal F$ and $A_0\in\mathcal F$, $x\notin A_0$ which is a contradiction. So it must be the case that $x\in\bigcup!\mathcal F$.

Case $2.$ Suppose $A_0$ is not unique. So we can choose $B_0$ such that $A_0\neq B_0$, $B_0\in \mathcal F$, and $x\in B_0$. Since $\mathcal F$ is pairwise disjoint, then $A_0\cap B_0=\emptyset$. From $A_0\cap B_0=\emptyset$ and $x\in A_0$ we obtain $x\notin B_0$ which contradicts $x\in B_0$. So it must be the case that $x\in\bigcup!\mathcal F$.

Since the above cases are exhaustive, $x\in\bigcup!\mathcal F$. Thus if $x\in\bigcup\mathcal F$ then $x\in\bigcup!\mathcal F$. Since $x$ is arbitrary, $\forall x(x\in\bigcup\mathcal F\rightarrow x\in\bigcup!\mathcal F)$ and so $\bigcup\mathcal F\subseteq \bigcup!\mathcal F$. Therefore if $\mathcal F$ is pairwise disjoint then $\bigcup\mathcal F\subseteq \bigcup!\mathcal F$. Adding the result from lemma $1$ we obtain if $\mathcal F$ is pairwise disjoint then $\bigcup\mathcal F= \bigcup!\mathcal F$.

Ergo $\bigcup!\mathcal F=\bigcup\mathcal F$ iff $\mathcal F$ is pairwise disjoint. $Q.E.D.$

Is my proof valid $($specifically that I am using lemma $1$ in that way$)$$?$

**One other question:** In the above linked-post, specifically in the given answer, the contradiction is not broken into different cases. Is it OK to ignore the cases like that and take them for granted$?$

Thanks for your attention.

Comment: Case 1 doesn't need to be included.  The very first assumption in the $\leftarrow$ part, when you introduced $x$, is that $x \in \bigcup\mathcal{F}$

Comment: @BrianMoehring Is it redundant or wrong?

Comment: It's unnecessary.   If you have the disjunction $p\lor q$ then of course you may use cases on $p$ and $q$, but if you also have $\lnot p$ then the cases become quite awkward.  Better to use $(\lnot p \land (p \lor q))\to q$ to skip the cases altogether.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your argument is correct, but part of it is superfluous, and the rest is unnecessarily wordy.

First, you don’t really need your lemma: it’s obvious from the definitions that $\bigcup!\mathscr{F}\subseteq\bigcup\mathscr{F}$. If you feel that you absolutely **must** justify it, it’s certainly enough to say something like this:

> Let $x\in\bigcup!\mathscr{F}$; by definition there is an $F\in\mathscr{F}$ such that $x\in F$, so $x\in\bigcup\mathscr{F}$.

For that argument it’s not important that $F$ is unique.

For the forward direction of the main result I’d prove the contrapositive, as **egreg** did in the answer to the linked question, but there’s nothing wrong with proving it directly. However, all you need is something like this:

> Suppose that $\bigcup!\mathscr{F}=\bigcup\mathscr{F}$, and suppose that $A,B\in\mathscr{F}$ with $A\ne B$. Then for any $x\in A$ we have $x\in A\subseteq\bigcup\mathscr{F}=\bigcup!\mathscr{F}$, so $A$ must be the unique element of $\mathscr{F}$ containing $x$. But then $x\notin B$, so $A\cap B=\varnothing$.

For the reverse implication your division into cases is completely unnecessary, and in any case there’s no need to argue by contradiction. You start off fine. After a little tightening up, your opening is essentially this:

> Now suppose that $\mathscr{F}$ is pairwise disjoint. Clearly $\bigcup!\mathscr{F}\subseteq\bigcup\mathscr{F}$, so let $x\in\bigcup\mathscr{F}$. There is some $A\in\mathscr{F}$ such that $x\in A$.

You’ve assumed that $x\in\bigcup\mathscr{F}$, so you’ve already ruled out your Case $1$: you really don’t have that case at all. If you choose to argue by contradiction, your Case $2$ is the only case.

But you don’t really need to go for a contradiction. If $A\ne B\in\mathscr{F}$, then by hypothesis $A\cap B=\varnothing$, so $x\notin B$, and $A$ is therefore the unique member of $\mathscr{F}$ containing $x$. Thus, by definition $x\in\bigcup!\mathscr{F}$, so $\bigcup\mathscr{F}\subseteq\bigcup!\mathscr{F}$, and hence $\bigcup!\mathscr{F}=\bigcup\mathscr{F}$.

Comment: As always, thanks for the time that you put into answering my question. :$)$

Comment: @KhashayarBaghizadeh: You’re welcome.